# Which LEGO set are these parts from?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

[image: Pile of LEGO bricks, including R2-D2, yellow and grey bricks]

As we don't know how to make....and which set.

Comment: Not knowing how to build a set doesn't seem urgent to me. LEGO sets are not intended to be built in a hurry.

Comment: And if you don't know which set it is, how does it relate to the LEGO Movie?  We do amazing things here, but we can't make the parts fly together like they did in the movie.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the

[yellow 30150 Container, Crate with Handholds](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30150#T=C)

and

[Trans-Bright Green Bar 8L with Round End (Spring Shooter Dart)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15303&idColor=108#T=C&C=108)

(also R2-D2)

You have:

[75092-1: Naboo Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75092-1/Naboo-Starfighter)
[image]